# Can't remove the cell after delete the dictionary in the 2D array

Tags: objective-c

I am writing a small app. Which filter and sorted the table like in the iphone contact list.
However mine is a bit different that there are options for user to choose filter from A->Z or from Z->A or not filter at all (which will remove the section title)

The logic is I load the data from all file plist and the items in there are dictionary, and each dictionary has 3 string objects.

I make an array called arrayData and get all the items into there. Then I call filter function:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)filterArray
{

    NSMutableArray *filterArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    [filterArr addObject:tempArray];
    [tempArray release];

    for (NSDictionary *item in arrayData) {
        if ([tempArray count]==0)
        {
            [tempArray addObject:item];
        }
        else
        {
            NSDictionary *anItem = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *first = [[anItem objectForKey:@"url"] substringToIndex:1];
            NSString *last = [[item objectForKey:@"url"] substringToIndex:1];

            if ( [first isEqualToString:last]) 
            {
                [tempArray addObject:item];
            } else
            {
                tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [tempArray addObject:item];
                [filterArr addObject:tempArray];
                [tempArray release];
            }
        }
    }
    return filterArr;
}
```

and I put it into a sortedArray:

```
NSMutableArray *filterArr = [self filterArray];

sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:filterArr copyItems:YES];
```

so in my table I just display :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if([sortedArray count]>0){

        NSLog(@"number of section: %d", [sortedArray count]);
        return [sortedArray count];
    }
    return 0;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = myOwnCell;
    }

    NSDictionary *dataItem = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.urlName.text = [dataItem objectForKey:@"url"];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [dataItem objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.urlName.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
    cell.imageIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dataItem objectForKey:@"image"]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
}
```

Now I wanna add delete function to delete the selected cell. However I does not help me delete correctly. It does not remove anything . I am not sure I do anything wrong with the deletion or not.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
     NSMutableDictionary *dataItem = [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [sortedArray removeObject:dataItem ];

}
```

PLease help me to talk a lot if I am missing or do something wrong. Thanks in advance